# Kafka KSQLDB Stream doesnt read topic

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have a system that produces messages to a topic: `user_event`

I created a stream from the data:

```
CREATE STREAM UserEventStream (
    type STRING,
    bundle_version BIGINT,
    app_version STRING,
    os_name STRING,
    device_id STRING,
    session_id STRING,
    device_type STRING,
    device_name STRING,
    device_brand STRING,
    language STRING,
    ip STRING,
    user_agent STRING,
    user_id BIGINT,
    fcm_token STRING,
    iframe BOOLEAN,
    referrer STRING,
    data MAP<STRING, STRING>,
    time BIGINT
) WITH (
    KAFKA_TOPIC='user_event',
    VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO'
);
```

When I try a simple query like: `SELECT * FROM UserEventStream;` it doesnt return anything, but the topic gets new data every second.

The messages are in correct format.

It was working like a week ago, it read the the topic perfectly. I dont think I did anything with it or the server.

**The kafka, schema registry, ksqldb, [kafka-ui](https://docs.kafka-ui.provectus.io/overview/readme) instance runs on a virtual machine without docker.**

Here is the avro message schema:

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "UserEvent",
    "namespace": "com.mycompany.kafka.records",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "type",
            "type": {
                "type": "string",
                "avro.java.string": "String"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "bundle_version",
            "type": [
                "null",
                "long"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "app_version",
            "type": [
                "null",
                {
                    "type": "string",
                    "avro.java.string": "String"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "os_name",
            "type": [
                "null",
                {
                    "type": "string",
                    "avro.java.string": "String"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "device_id",
            "type": {
                "type": "string",
                "avro.java.string": "String"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "session_id",
            "type": [
                "null",
                {
                    "type": "string",
                    "avro.java.string": "String"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "device_type",
            "type": [
                "null",
                {
                    "type": "string",
                    "avro.java.string": "String"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "device_name",
            "type": [
                "null",
                {
                    "type": "string",
                    "avro.java.string": "String"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "device_brand",
            "type": [
                "null",
                {
                    "type": "string",
                    "avro.java.string": "String"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "language",
            "type": [
                "null",
                {
                    "type": "string",
                    "avro.java.string": "String"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "ip",
            "type": [
                "null",
                {
                    "type": "string",
                    "avro.java.string": "String"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "user_agent",
            "type": [
                "null",
                {
                    "type": "string",
                    "avro.java.string": "String"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "user_id",
            "type": [
                "null",
                "long"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "fcm_token",
            "type": [
                "null",
                {
                    "type": "string",
                    "avro.java.string": "String"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "iframe",
            "type": "boolean"
        },
        {
            "name": "referrer",
            "type": [
                "null",
                {
                    "type": "string",
                    "avro.java.string": "String"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "data",
            "type": {
                "type": "map",
                "values": [
                    "null",
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "avro.java.string": "String"
                    }
                ],
                "avro.java.string": "String"
            },
            "default": {}
        },
        {
            "name": "time",
            "type": {
                "type": "long",
                "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/ksqldb/operations.html#no-results-from-select-from-table-or-stream

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

The problem was that the stream's columns were not defined properly, and it didnt tell me anything about it.

So I created the stream like this:

```
CREATE STREAM UserEventStream WITH (
    KAFKA_TOPIC='user_event',
    VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO'
);
```

It recognized the schema from the registry and created the right columns. Now it works perfectly.